# JavaScript Object notation - using methods inside the same object?

Tags: javascript, reusability, object-notation

i experimenting with node.js and i have a set of methods that are being exported using `module.exports` however some of the methods are meant to be reusable with the same object but i am not sure how to go about this. In PHP i would simply reference `this`. I know `this` can be referenced in prototype objects, but can the same be done in JavaScript Object Notation?

**Example code:**

```
module.export = {

    foo: (a, b) => {
        return a + b;
    },

    bar: () => {
       return foo(2, 5); // This is where i run into problems, using 'this' has no effect.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword in JavaScript. The only other change you will have to make is use actual functions instead of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), since arrow functions don't capture `this` scope.

Here is a quote from the [MDN page on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.

Because it doesn't have its own `this` you can't use arrow functions in this case.

Below is an example of how you can refactor your code to work the way you are expecting.

```
module.export = {

    foo: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    },

    bar: function () {
       return this.foo(2, 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, short-hand methods would be closer to the use-case here: `foo(a, b){ return a + b; }, bar(){ return this.foo(2, 5) }`, since those behave similarly to arrow functions but also have their own `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Having had ES6 hammered into my skull along with arrow functions i just assumed that it would function the same way. Now i am not so sure it is worth saving the extra few characters.

Comment: @Xufox, are you saying that you can omit the method key/name is this case ? as in foo: function() {} can be written just foo() {} ?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers Yes. It’s [short-hand method notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). They are, like arrow functions, not constructible (cannot be `new`’d).